# Replace high values with forward filling

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe of which some features contain very high outliers. I would like to get rid of those sudden very high values

```
ax.plot(df['Temperature'])
```

[image]

To lessen this effect i used `clip` depending on the quantiles, but it does not work as good as i would like.

```
ax.plot(df['Temperature'].clip(lower=df['Temperature'].quantile(0.05), upper=df['Temperature'].quantile(0.95)))
```

[image]

How can i replace these (very high) values with their previous ones with forward filling? If the Temperature jump at `df('Temperature')[100]` until `df('Temperature')[120]` then replace these values with `df('Temperature')[99]`

Comment: Using `clip` makes the aberrant values harder to detect, so you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: True, it doesnt seem to help

Comment: Are the outliers all equal? Looks like a value of exactly `100` to me for each of them. That would make it very easy to mask them out and replace as needed. If not, you may want to pick a threshold instead.

Comment: Yes, indeed the outliers are all equal. I dont know the reason of this (probably some sort of calibration) so i would like to "ignore" this effect for now. Replacing them with forward fill perhaps can be a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `NaN` the indices that are invalid, then use `fillna` to backfill them?

```py
>>> seq = np.arange(0, 10)
>>> seq[4:7] *= 100
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(seq, columns=['temp'])
   temp
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4   400
5   500
6   600
7     7
8     8
9     9
>>> df[df.temp>=300] = np.nan  # adjust the condition accordingly
   temp
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   7.0
8   8.0
9   9.0
>>> df.fillna(method='backfill')
   temp
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   7.0
5   7.0
6   7.0
7   7.0
8   8.0
9   9.0
```